# VSCode "Commit staged" successful but GitHub is not updated

Tags: github

Successfully linked up a repository from GitHub to local, after editing, file `model\genre.js` needs to be upload and commit back to GitHub. So, I did,

1. In Source Control panel, in **Changed** list, click on the "+" sign to make it to staged. File advanced from **Changed** to **Staged**.
2. Same panel, click on `...` from the top, then "`Commit staged`", hit Enter.
3. This file is gone from `Staged` list, now only package.json and package-lock.json left in Changed list which is alright as I don't want to touch the masters in GitHub.

Looks perfect. Checking GitHub, oops, shows update was 2 hrs ago, refresh the page, still. Opened up the file and check, not having my latest update.

Is it because I didn't ***Fork*** it beforehand?  I'm a bit hesitate to `git push origin master --force`

Here is the Git output from VSCode:

```
Using git 2.10.2.windows.1 from C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
git status -z -u
git config --get commit.template
git fetch
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse master
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref master@{u}
git rev-list --left-right master...origin/master
git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname)
git remote --verbose
git status -z -u
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse master
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref master@{u}
git rev-list --left-right master...origin/master
git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname)
git remote --verbose
git show :app.js
git show :populatedb.js
git fetch
git status -z -u
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse master
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref master@{u}
git rev-list --left-right master...origin/master
git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname)
git remote --verbose
git show :populatedb.js
git fetch
git show :populatedb.js
git status -z -u
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse master
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref master@{u}
git rev-list --left-right master...origin/master
git show :populatedb.js
git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname)
git remote --verbose
git fetch
git show :populatedb.js
git status -z -u
git show :populatedb.js
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse master
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref master@{u}
git rev-list --left-right master...origin/master
git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname)
git remote --verbose
git status -z -u
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse master
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref master@{u}
git rev-list --left-right master...origin/master
git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname)
git remote --verbose
git status -z -u
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse master
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref master@{u}
git rev-list --left-right master...origin/master
git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname)
git remote --verbose
git status -z -u
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse master
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref master@{u}
git rev-list --left-right master...origin/master
git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname)
git remote --verbose
git fetch
git status -z -u
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse master
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref master@{u}
git rev-list --left-right master...origin/master
git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname)
git remote --verbose
git show :populatedb.js
git show :models/genre.js
git status -z -u
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse master
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref master@{u}
git rev-list --left-right master...origin/master
git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname)
git remote --verbose
git fetch
git status -z -u
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse master
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref master@{u}
git rev-list --left-right master...origin/master
git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname)
git remote --verbose
git show :models/genre.js
git show HEAD:models/genre.js
git add -A -- c:\Users\Admin\Documents\LEARN\express-locallibrary-tutorial\models\genre.js
git status -z -u
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse master
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref master@{u}
git rev-list --left-right master...origin/master
git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname)
git remote --verbose
git show :models/genre.js
git fetch
git status -z -u
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse master
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref master@{u}
git rev-list --left-right master...origin/master
git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname)
git remote --verbose
git show :models/genre.js
git commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
git status -z -u
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse master
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref master@{u}
git rev-list --left-right master...origin/master
git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname)
git remote --verbose
git show HEAD:models/genre.js
git fetch
git status -z -u
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse master
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref master@{u}
git rev-list --left-right master...origin/master
git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname)
git remote --verbose
git show HEAD:models/genre.js
git fetch
git status -z -u
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse master
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref master@{u}
git rev-list --left-right master...origin/master
git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname)
git remote --verbose
git show HEAD:models/genre.js
git status -z -u
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse master
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref master@{u}
git rev-list --left-right master...origin/master
git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname)
git remote --verbose
git show :models/genre.js
git fetch
git status -z -u
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse master
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref master@{u}
git rev-list --left-right master...origin/master
git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname)
git remote --verbose
git show :models/genre.js
git fetch
git status -z -u
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse master
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref master@{u}
git rev-list --left-right master...origin/master
git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname)
git remote --verbose
git show :models/genre.js
```

Comment: I don't push normally through VS so I'll only comment rather than give half an answer at best, but I don't see anywhere there with a push (without `--force` which is necessary if you've rewritten the local history in some way). Did you go to the Synchronization tab and push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after vscode commited the changes you need to push it from terminal

Comment: Awesome! Here is needed after step 3 above.
4. **Need to push after commit.** Click on ... again, select Push, fill in your GitHub login when the prompt comes up. Wala, it's in.
Interesting thing is GitHub shows update time is 39 min. ago vs. 2 min. ago. Means commit already has things uploaded into GitHub. The terms are very confusing, Commit usually is the last step, for example C# coding and SQL including Oracle.